# Convert Select2 array output to string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I am trying to convert select2 array to string to be used in form. Currently my output looks like this:

> ?source%5B%5D=x1&source%5B%5D=x2

i am looking to convert it to have comma separated string. I have tried to use 'string = source.join()' but output of my string is empty.

> %5B%5D=x1&source%5B%5D=x2&string=

What I am trying to get is something like this:

> string%5B%5D=x1,x2

```
<form action="/action_page.php">    
   <select class="form-control select2" multiple="" id="source" name="source[]" style="width: 250px;">

      <optgroup label="Group1">
         <option>x1</option>
         <option>x2</option></optgroup>
         <optgroup label="Group2">
            <option>y1</option>
            <option>y2</option></optgroup>
         </select>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".select2").select2({
            tags: true
            });
         </script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         string = source.join()
         </script>
         <input type='hidden' name='string' ></input>
         <br><br>
         <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's really what you want, but that can give you clues.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="onFormSubmit()">

   <select class="form-control select2" multiple="" id="source" style="width: 250px;">
      <optgroup label="Group1">
         <option>x1</option>
         <option>x2</option>
       </optgroup>
       <optgroup label="Group2">
          <option>y1</option>
          <option>y2</option>
      </optgroup>
   </select>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      // Init Select2
      var mySelect = $(".select2").select2({
        tags: true
      });
      // On form submit
      var onFormSubmit = function(){
        // Get selected value (only if at least one selected)
        if (mySelect.val() !== null && mySelect.val().length > 0) {
            var selectedSource = "string=" + mySelect.val().join(',');
            alert(selectedSource);
        }
      }
   </script>
   <input type='hidden' name='string' />
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but above gives me the same output as previously: "source[]=x1&source[]=x2". What I am trying to get is: "string=x1,x2"

Comment: This is still not exactly what I am looking for. You create string in selectedSource but this is not being added to the form.

Comment: It worked by adding document.getElementById('string').value = mySelect.val().join(','); Thank you both for your help!

Comment: :-) glad to help

Comment: Hi, may I know what is the `name="source[]"` used for? It is compulsory need to have in the HTML? Because I don't see it use somewhere. thank you.

Comment: @mastersuse you're right, in this example it's not needed, it has been removed. Project where this code was inspired had js component who used name attribute.