# How to convert select2 array output to single string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

How to convert `select2` array output to single string (separated by comma)? Just like this `"task_owner":"Administrator,abc2"`. Current output is separated by comma but in single array `"task_owner":["Administrator","abc2"]`. This is because the DB is received by string, not array.

Another question, how to re-convert back to array since during editing, Ajax will send that String from DB and I maybe need to convert back to Array for display purpose.

I was referred to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663005/convert-select2-array-output-to-string) but not working.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <select type="text" class="form-control myClass" id="myID" multiple="multiple"></select>
</form>

$('.myClass').select2({
    tags: true
 });    

$('#btnSubmit').on('click',function(){
    var testOutput = "";   // I put this because an error appear so I create a new var but the output is = "null", why?
    var owner = $('#myID').val();

    if (owner.val() !== null && owner.val().length > 0){
        var testOutput = $('#myID') = owner.val().join(',');
        testOutput = Object.assign({}, {task_owner: testOutput.task_owner.join(",")})
    }

    // parameter that need to send to API
    var obj = {
        task_owner : testOutput,
        // Another parameter...
    };
    var params = JSON.stringify(obj);

    $.ajax({
        // My Ajax Condition...
    });
});
```

Comment: `var testOutput = $('#myID') = mySelect.val().join(',');`
            
`testOutput = Object.assign({}, {task_owner: testOutput.task_owner.join(",")})`

Comment: hi, inside curly `Object.assign({}` need to store anything? or just be like that? sorry I am new.

Comment: just like that! It is to merge 2 object

Comment: Sorry OR just use
`var testOutput = $('#myID') = mySelect.val().join(','); 
testOutput = {task_owner: testOutput.task_owner.join(",")}`

Comment: I don't get the answer, wait I will update my question with proper code and let you know.

Comment: Ok I just update my question with proper structured code. Hopefully you can answer in complete code at answer section.

Comment: Please check my asnwer. you question is to vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dicussed:

```
$(".myClass").select2({
  tags: true
});

$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function() {
  var testOutput = ""; // I put this because an error appear so I create a new var but the output is = "null", why?
  var owner = $("#myID").val(); //
  if (Array.isArray(owner) && owner.length) {
    testOutput = owner.join(",");
  }
  var obj = {
    task_owner: testOutput
  };
  var params = JSON.stringify(obj);

  $.ajax({
    // My Ajax Condition...
  });
});
```

Comment: If you are not busy, could you help me again on this? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60900754/how-to-split-and-display-from-string-to-array-for-select2-jquery?noredirect=1#comment107746970_60900754)

Comment: What in now missing??

Comment: This posting is completely done, but have another link, just provide above.